# Ability to add more details when flagging post as spam

Tags: feature-request, flags, spam

I flagged a post by [this user](https://superuser.com/users/58052/user58052) because it smells like spam. I wanted to include additional details that most of their other answers are the exact same text as well.

Would this be possible? Or should I be flagging their other posts as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In that case, you can (and should) opt for the "other" variety of flag and fill the details into the description field.